# Gnuplot add labels on y2

Tags: label, gnuplot, gnu

When i try to add labels on y2 (on the green line so i can see the percentage as label/text) i get this error: "Not enough columns for this style".

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y/%m/%d'

set xtics 30*24*60*60
set datafile separator ','

set table 'temporaryfile.dat'
set format x '%Y/%m/%d'
plot 'updated.csv' using (timecolumn(1) - (tm_mday(timecolumn(1))-1)*24*60*60):(1) smooth frequency 
unset table

set y2tics 5
set ytics nomirror
set timefmt '"%Y/%m/%d"'
set format x '%b %Y'
set xtics rotate by 90 right
set format y2 "%g %%"

set grid ytics xtics
set y2range [0:100]
set ytics 10

set term png
set output 'file.png'
set terminal png size 2800,900

set datafile separator white
set yrange[0:*]
x0=x1=0
plot 'temporaryfile.dat' using 1:(strcol(3) eq "i" ? $2 : 1/0) w lp pt 7 ps 2 title 'IP/URL Count', \
     '' using 1:(x1=x0, x0=$2, strcol(3) eq "i" ? ($0 == 0 || x0 == 0 ? 0 : (x0-x1)/x0 * 100.0) : 1/0) axes x1y2 w labels
```

Comment: As the message says: for plotting labels you must give three columns in `using`

Comment: Thanks Christoph you are the one that helped me with that script in first place, i want to ask you if i an third column with text can i show the percentage of a word (in how many rows is the same word) and also use labels in the y2 (percentage) also?